# Detecting when application becoming active coming from background

Tags: android

When my application comes back from background, it goes to the last activity (screen).
I would like it to go to the home screen instead - How I can accomplish that?
Or, how to detect event when whole application (not activity) comes from background to the front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out to call `finish()` on the `onPause()` method of that activity which is restoring on getting the application to foreground. This will finish that activity and now your home activity will be on top in the Activity Stack and displayed first on restore to foreground.

Comment: Thanks, it may work, but I was looking for some code on application level.  What you are suggesting I have to implement in each activity.  On top of that, I have to check if application is just navigating among its own activities / screens, in wich case I do not want to "finish()", or whole app goes into background

Comment: humm You can try this FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT (the document describes exactly what you want to) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Answer (score 3):

If you are building off of 'runnable' you can override `onPause` and `onResume`.

Comment: It's actually "activity" that you're referring to.

Comment: how about onRestart callback. That is called only when your activities come back right. I think we can use that for detection.

Answer (score 1):

Changing normal task's "stack" behavior is possible in many ways, but it's *quite not simple*. Some options are achievable with startActivity() flags, some others through properties of the manifest's `<activity>` element. Some are available in both ways, some not. Some work only if combined with others, some change behavior if combined with others. I feel really confused with these features.

Luckily [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) simple option might be what you're interested in.